# how to get the text value of the selected drowdown

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i want to get the text which is selected from the dropdown value and want to print it

```
Select m = new Select(ActivityPage.Frommonth);
m.selectByIndex(2);// it will select month februaray
Thread.sleep(2000);
String frommonth = m.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();// i want to print the februaray
```

- Expected output: February
- Actual output: Month

Comment: Could you please format your code properly so that its readable? And could you please state the specific problem you're facing with the code you wrote?

Comment: hello sir ,   suppose user has selected some value from dropdown list , after selecting user want to get the selected value and print it . here , i have selected month from drop down list after that i want to get the value which is selected as dropdown option ! how could i do it , i have tried

Comment: @Dib Update the question with the relevant HTML. How is `ActivityPage` defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```
Select dropDown = new Select(Driver.findElement(PUT_YOUR_ELEMENTS_XPATH_CSS_OR_OTHER)));
List<WebElement> e = dropDown.getOptions();
int size = e.size();

for(int x = 0; x <  size; x++)
{
    System.out.println(e.get(x).getText());
    if (e.get(l).getText().equals("February") {
       System.out.println("I found february")
    } else {
       System.out.println("I can't see Fenruary")
       }
}
```